# PHP Extracting Sub-String from a String

Tags: php

Say I have a string containing the following...

```
    <meta property="og:title" content="Product Name"/>
```

And I want to search the string and retrieve Product Name and then store it as a separate variable.

Any ideas to point me in the right direction? I've tried regular expressions without luck here

Comment: Do you have multiple meta tags same like above? And want to fetch all meta tags content in PHP?

Comment: `strpos` and `substr` is what you're looking for http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php || http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: Are you looking for php get_meta_tags http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php

Comment: Hi, not looking for get_meta_tags - these meta property's are in the source code of a website. I'm doing a file_get_contents to load the entire content of a webpage into a variable, and then trying to extract just the contents of the meta tags

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have look over below code, I've implemented regex to fetch the content of meta tags. Demo [link](https://eval.in/805312)

```
$metas = [
   '<meta property="og:title" content="Product Name1"/>',
   '<meta property="og:title" content="Product Name2"/>',
   '<meta property="og:title" content="Product Name3"/>'
];
foreach($metas as $meta){
   preg_match('/<meta.*?content="(.*?)"\/>/s',$meta,$matches);
       echo $matches[1]."<br>";
}
```